# Hiding "index.php" at url in "YII" when using "https" does not work

Tags: .htaccess, https, yii

here i am stuck with a small problem. I have a site built in Yii framework. It runs without any problem with http protocol (the index.php in url is hidden and all urls work fine). I have hosted this in amazon ec2 services. i have the following lines in my .htaccess file

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

IndexIgnore */*
RewriteEngine on

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

but when i use https to browse the site (note: i have it all configured) , the home page loads normally. but the other urls does not work and requires /index.php/ to be added. what am i missing here?

dying for answers.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you set showScriptName to false in your config file?

Comment: // uncomment the following to enable URLs in path-format
  'urlManager'=>array(
   'urlFormat'=>'path',
         'showScriptName'=>false,
   'rules'=>array(
    '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
    '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
    '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
   ),
  ),

Comment: yes, showScriptName is false in the config ...

Comment: Did you check if the same urls work with http? Your .htaccess looks fine and should work fine for http and https.

Comment: yes, hiding .index.php with http works fine. i also believed that it will work until i tested with https. i tried adding "RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L]" to my htaccess file ...

Answer (score 3):

To get mod_rewrite working not only mod_rewrite must be installed, but also check in the Apache directory config (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default on Ubuntu installed via apt-get) if the rule "AllowOverride None" exists in your project's directory config. If so, change it to "AllowOverride All".

```
#
# AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
# It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
#   Options FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
#
**AllowOverride All**
```

mod_rewrite can be installed by remove comment from this line

```
#LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

Answer (score 1):

After a long search for the .htaccess configurations, main file configurations, the solution was found in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled directory , in the default-ssl file. (thanks to Hemc's answer)

this is what i did. this may help some others:

first move to the apache's sites-enabled directory

```
cd /etc/apache2/sites-enabled
```

then open default-ssl file

```
sudo vi default-ssl
```

then change **AllowOverride None** to **AllowOverride All**

Actually this is in the top of my file and it works fine .ie. my index.php is properly hidden and urls work fine :)

```
    <IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DocumentRoot /var/www
    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
            AllowOverride None
            Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>
```

And finally after saving and quitting, dont forget to restart your apache

```
 sudo service apache2 restart
```

thanks